# how to colorize PHP result image using GD

Tags: php, gd, colorize

I have a code that resize and colorize the image accordingly input values... the problem is I can able to colorize only one time with fresh image saved by other application..Please help me.. I hope there are many PHP expers are here.....

```
<?php
createImage(50,50, 0,0, 255);
function createImage($width, $height, $nR, $nG, $nB)
{
$image = imagecreatefrompng("source.png");
imagealphablending($image, false);  
imagesavealpha($image, true);       

      //resize the image
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagealphablending($new_image, false); 
      imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($image), imagesx($image));

    //colorize the image
        $nrgb = str_pad(dechex($nR), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). str_pad(dechex($nG), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). str_pad(dechex($nB), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);              

       $newColor = $nrgb;

        $c2 = sscanf($newColor ,"%2x%2x%2x");

        for($i=0;$i<$width;$i++)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<$height;$j++)
            {
             $cIndex = imagecolorat($new_image,$i,$j);

             imagecolorset($new_image,$cIndex,$c2[0],$c2[1],$c2[2]);
            }
        }

        header("Content-Type: image/png");

        imagepng($new_image,"test.png");
}
?>
```

Comment: You should provide some code, and better explain the problem. It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "colorize". Ideally, a "before/after" screenshot

Comment: wait let me prepare short version of my problem.....thanks for your quick response...

Comment: there for you test.... please fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are manipulating an image resource and outputting it and then wanting to go back and further manipulate it without starting over.  You can do this by

a) save the image resource as a session variable, and then use the session variable in subsequent alterations.

b) save the altered image before outputting it, and then open the saved altered image and go from there. I don't know what file type you are using but for instance with gif images your code should be using imagegif() to output the image.  You would utilize this same function (or other image type equivalent function) to also save the image.

Comment: the above code works fine without problem... but we shoule color the image first before resize... that is the problem...

Comment: so you are saying your script first outputs the original image, accepts input to resize it, then outputs the resized image and now you want to accept input to recolor it, using the resized image? Then yes, you need to save the altered image using one of the methods described.

Comment: and it looks like from your posted code above, you are saving the file as test.png.  So when you go back to recolor it, you would use imagecreatefrompng() instead of imagecreatetruecolor() to create the image source from an existing file.

Comment: hello Crayon.... you did not see my full code.. sorry for the half post... please take a look.. I think you can able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the imagefilter function found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

Look at `IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE` on that page.