# How to do resize and color change png image in php GD

Tags: php, image, png, colorize

```
<?php
createImage(50,50, 0,0, 255);
function createImage($width, $height, $nR, $nG, $nB)
{
$image = imagecreatefrompng("source.png");
imagealphablending($image, false);  
imagesavealpha($image, true);       

      //resize the image
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagealphablending($new_image, false); 
      imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($image), imagesx($image));

    //colorize the image
        $nrgb = str_pad(dechex($nR), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). str_pad(dechex($nG), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). str_pad(dechex($nB), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);              

       $newColor = $nrgb;

        $c2 = sscanf($newColor ,"%2x%2x%2x");

        for($i=0;$i<$width;$i++)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<$height;$j++)
            {
             $cIndex = imagecolorat($new_image,$i,$j);

             imagecolorset($new_image,$cIndex,$c2[0],$c2[1],$c2[2]);
            }
        }

        header("Content-Type: image/png");

        imagepng($new_image,"test.png");
}
?>
```

Comment: the above code works when change the color first then resize. but I needs in reverse order... please help me

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to colorize PHP result image using GD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235941/how-to-colorize-php-result-image-using-gd)

Comment: yes it's me...I have a code here

Comment: Crayon Violent -- here it is my revised code... please take a look.

Comment: You create a truecolor image, and then scale it down. This will change the tint of invidivual pixels due to neighboring pixel colors getting merged. Searching for a specific RGB value will fail therefore.

Answer (score 0):

No expert here... so far after one month research and hard study I found the answer for above solution......just a couple of min ago... we have to use imagecreate funciton instead of imagecreatetruecolor... coz trucolor function generate 32bit png image...we could not colorize 32 bit image using imagecolorset function.. how tricky it is....lol.. thanks for the support of crayon...